# Passing dynamic object into method

Tags: c#, dynamic, methods

I am fairly new to using dynamic in c# and I am getting a weird error I hoped someone could help me explain or solve.

I am doing the following :

```
Class1
{
  Class2 _otherClass = new Class2();

 private void SendToClass2()
 {
   dynamic data =  new ExpandoObject();
   data.value1 = "Hello Wrold";
   data.value2 = some unknown type // (for simplicity let's say another string)   

   _otherClass.UseTheValues(data)
 }
}
```

Class 2 is built like

```
Class2
{
  UseTheValues(object T)
  {
    Serialize (T)
  } 
}
```

This works fine while I am debugging, I can view the dynamic data as :

```
data Dynamic Results: 
[0] {[ Value1, "Hello World" ]}
[1] {[ Value2, value ]}
```

So the data seems to be created correctly,
however at run-time on a different machine I am getting an exception :

> Type : Action_Error | From : Class 1 | Location : SendToClass2()
>
> CSharp Binder.RuntimeBinderException : 'data' does not contain a
> definition for UseTheValues.

am I missing something obvious here?

**EDIT** : I should probably add that the error occurred after it was sent to our nightly build which scrambles the variables, functions, methods etc. to make it harder for an outsider to see what is being done and the error message appeared as

> 'c2565dssad6f5ds6fsdf65' does not contain a definition of UseTheValues

I am thinking maybe it has something to do with "UseTheValues" being treated as a dynamic expression which is only resolved at run-time.

**EDIT 2** Yeah it turns out it has to do with our nightly builder who scrambles the code, but can't scramble the dynamic expression and therefore throws an error when the scrambled variable tries to access the (non)scrambled version of the method.

Comment: We don't really have enough context here. Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Umm...so the problem was a custom obfuscation tool that doesn't support a language feature that you are using? Maybe you would like to close this question.

Comment: Yes that's exactly right

Comment: @Johan What are you passing for data.value2 ? You told it is : "some unknown type" , but are you sure you are not passing instance of "Class2" itself to it?

Comment: @Siva I was using it as a dynamic container as I was sending a variety of value types depending on what was needed, I was not passing class 2 to itself though :)